# Is the dot product considered to be between a vector and a covector?

Tags: inner-products

A vector times a covector is of course a scalar. 
Is the dot product considered to be between a vector and a covector or is it considered to be between 2 vectors?

If between 2 vectors then can I assume that

$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b  \\
c 
\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y  \\
z 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b  \\
c 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x &
y &
z 
\end{bmatrix}=
a x + b y + c z$

where the tensor is a (0,2) tensor?

The obvious example of a dot product is gravity times displacement which give the energy released per mass. Displacement is clearly a vector but gravity has units of energy per distance per mass which sounds like a covector to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (0,2) tensor is a linear function that takes as its input two vectors and outputs a scalar. So the dot product is an example of a (0,2) tensor.

But you can also think of a (0,2) tensor as a function that takes one vector as input and outputs a co-vector. So the metric tensor, which is a generalisation of the dot product, can be thought of as a function that transforms a vector into an equivalent co-vector.